# How can I sort an array dataset in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, filter

I am trying to sort a column in Excel by greatest to least but I am running into this error. "You can't change part of an array"

The column formula is:

```
=COUNTIFS(' Line Listing'!N:N,B59,' Line Listing'!P:P,"yes")
```

This formula counts the number of times something occurs based off 2 criteria, 1 being it matches the name in B59 and if the other column says yes.

How can I make it so that I am able to sort this data? or make this data in such a way it is sortable?

Thank you!

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

Comment: You have an array formula somewhere in your data that you're trying to filter. That CountIfs function isn't it. Maybe somewhere with brackets around the formula?

Comment: Thanks Boss! Column B was an array. I changed it so it was just a normal dataset and now it works great.